# Running Scipy Linregress Across Dataframe Where Each Element is a List

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am working with a Pandas dataframe where each element contains a list of values. I would like to run a regression between the lists in the first column and the lists in each subsequent column for every row in the dataframe, and store the t-stats of each regression (currently using a numpy array to store them). I am able to do this using a nested for loop that loops through each row and column, but the performance is not optimal for the amount of data I am working with.

Here is a quick sample of what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [list(np.random.rand(11)) for i in range(100)],
     'b': [list(np.random.rand(11)) for i in range(100)],
     'c': [list(np.random.rand(11)) for i in range(100)],
     'd': [list(np.random.rand(11)) for i in range(100)],
     'e': [list(np.random.rand(11)) for i in range(100)],
     'f': [list(np.random.rand(11)) for i in range(100)]
    }
)
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
0   [0.279347961395256, 0.07198822780319691, 0.209...   [0.4733815106836531, 0.5807425586417414, 0.068...   [0.9377037591435088, 0.9698329284595916, 0.241...   [0.03984770879654953, 0.650429630364027, 0.875...   [0.04654151678901641, 0.1959629573862498, 0.36...   [0.01328000288459652, 0.10429773699794731, 0.0...
1   [0.1739544898167934, 0.5279297754363472, 0.635...   [0.6464841177367048, 0.004013634850660308, 0.2...   [0.0403944630279538, 0.9163938509072009, 0.350...   [0.8818108296208096, 0.2910758930807579, 0.739...   [0.5263032002243185, 0.3746299115677546, 0.122...   [0.5511171062367501, 0.327702669239891, 0.9147...
2   [0.49678125158054476, 0.807770957943305, 0.396...   [0.6218806473477556, 0.01720135741717188, 0.15...   [0.6110516368605904, 0.20848099927159314, 0.51...   [0.7473669581190695, 0.5107081859246958, 0.442...   [0.8231961741887535, 0.9686869510163731, 0.473...   [0.34358121300094313, 0.9787339533782848, 0.72...
3   [0.7672751789941814, 0.412055981587398, 0.9951...   [0.8470471648467321, 0.9967427749160083, 0.818...   [0.8591072331661481, 0.6279199806511635, 0.365...   [0.9456189188046846, 0.5084362869897466, 0.586...   [0.2685328112579779, 0.8893788305422594, 0.235...   [0.029919732007230193, 0.6377951981939682, 0.1...
4   [0.21420195955828203, 0.15178914447352077, 0.9...   [0.6865307542882283, 0.0620359602798356, 0.382...   [0.6469510945986712, 0.676059598071864, 0.0396...   [0.2320436872397288, 0.09558341089961908, 0.98...   [0.7733653233006889, 0.2405189745554751, 0.016...   [0.8359561624563979, 0.24335481664355396, 0.38...
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
95  [0.42373270776373506, 0.7731750012629109, 0.90...   [0.9430465078763153, 0.8506292743184455, 0.567...   [0.41367168515273345, 0.9040247409476362, 0.72...   [0.23016875953835192, 0.8206550830081965, 0.26...   [0.954233948805146, 0.995068745046983, 0.20247...   [0.26269690906898413, 0.5032835345055103, 0.26...
96  [0.36114607798432685, 0.11322299769211142, 0.0...   [0.729848741496316, 0.9946930423163686, 0.2265...   [0.17207915211677138, 0.3270055732644267, 0.73...   [0.13211243241239223, 0.28382298905995607, 0.2...   [0.03915259352564071, 0.05639914089770948, 0.0...   [0.12681415759423675, 0.006417761276839351, 0....
97  [0.5020186971295065, 0.04018166955309821, 0.19...   [0.9082402680300308, 0.1334790715379094, 0.991...   [0.7003469664104871, 0.9444397336912727, 0.113...   [0.7982221018200218, 0.9097963438776192, 0.163...   [0.07834894180973451, 0.7948519146738178, 0.56...   [0.5833962514812425, 0.403689767723475, 0.7792...
98  [0.16413822314461857, 0.40683312270714234, 0.4...   [0.07366489230864415, 0.2706766599711766, 0.71...   [0.6410967759869383, 0.5780018716586993, 0.622...   [0.5466463581695835, 0.4949639043264169, 0.749...   [0.40235314091318986, 0.8305539205264385, 0.35...   [0.009668651763079184, 0.8071825962911674, 0.0...
99  [0.8189246990381518, 0.69175150213841, 0.82687...   [0.40469941577758317, 0.49004906937461257, 0.7...   [0.4940080411615112, 0.33621539942693246, 0.67...   [0.8637418291877355, 0.34876318713083676, 0.09...   [0.3526913672876807, 0.5177762589812651, 0.746...   [0.3463129199717484, 0.9694802522161138, 0.732...
100 rows × 6 columns
```

My code to run the regressions and store the t-stats:

```
rows = len(df)
cols = len(df.columns)

tstats = np.zeros(shape=(rows,cols-1))

for i in range(0,rows):
    
    for j in range(1,cols):
        
        lg = linregress(df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,j])
        
        tstats[i,j-1] = lg.slope/lg.stderr
```

The code above works just fine and is doing exactly what I need, however as I mentioned above the performance begins to slow down when the # of rows and columns in df increases substantially.

I'm hoping someone could offer advice on how to optimize my code for better performance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am newbie to this but I do optimization your original code:

- by purely use python builtin list object (there is no need to use pandas and to be honest I cannot find a better way to solve your problem in pandas than you original code :D)
- by using numpy, which should be (at least they claimed) faster than python builtin list.

You can jump to see the code, its in Jupyter notebook format so you need to [install](https://jupyter.org/install) Jupyter first.

### Conclusion

Here is the test result:
On a (100, 100) matrix containing (30,) length random lists,
the total time difference is around 1 second.

```
Time elapsed to run 1 times on new method is 24.282760 seconds.
Time elapsed to run 1 times on old method is 25.954801 seconds.
```

Refer to
`test_perf`
in sample code for result.

PS: During test only one thread is used, so *maybe* multi-thread will help to improve performance, but that's out of my ability...

### Idea

I think `numpy.nditer` is suitable for your request, though the result of optimization is not that significant. Here is my idea:

1. Generate the input array

   I have altered you first part of script, I think using list comprehension along is enough to build a matrix of random lists. Refer to
   `get_matrix_from_builtin`.
   Please note I have stored the random lists in another 1-element tuple to keep the shape as ndarray generate from numpy.

   As a compare, you can also construct such matrix with numpy. Refer to
   `get_matrix_from_numpy`.
   Because ndarray try to boardcast list-like object (and I don't know how to stop it), I have to wrap it into a tuple to avoid auto boardcast from `numpy.array` constructor. If anyone have a better solution please note it, thanks :)
2. Calculate the result

   I altered you original code using `pandas.DataFrame` to access element by row/col index, but it is not that way.
   Pandas provides some iteration tool for DataFrame: `pipe`, `apply`, `agg`, and `appymap`, search API for more info, but it seems not suitable for your request here, as you want to obtain the current index of row and col during iteration.

   I searched and found `numpy.nditer` can provide that needs: it return a iterator of ndarray, which have an attribution `multi_index` that provide the row/col pair of current element. see [iterating-over-arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#iterating-over-arrays)

### Explain on solve.ipynb

I use Jupyter Notebook to test this, you might need got one, [here](https://jupyter.org/install) is the instruction of install.

I have altered your original code, which remove the request of pandas and purely used builtin list. Refer to
`old_calc_tstat`
in the sample code.

Also, I used `numpy.nditer` to calc your tstats matrix, Refer to
`new_calc_tstat`
in the sample code.

Then, I tested if the result of both methods are equal, I used same input array to ensure random won't affect the test. Refer to
`test_equal`
for result.

Finally, do the time performance. I am not patient so I only run it for one time, you may add the repeats count of test in the
`test_perf` function.

### The code

```
# To add a new cell, type '# %%'
# To add a new markdown cell, type '# %% [markdown]'
# %% [markdown]
# [origin question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228572/running-scipy-linregress-across-dataframe-where-each-element-is-a-list)
#

# %%
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress


# %%
def get_matrix_from_builtin():
    # use builtin list to construct matrix of random list
    # note I put random list inside a tuple to keep it same shape
    # as I later use numpy to do the same thing.
    return [
        [(list(np.random.rand(11)),)
         for col in range(6)]
        for row in range(100)
    ]


# %timeit get_matrix_from_builtin()


# %%
def get_matrix_from_numpy(
    gen=np.random.rand,
    shape=(1, 1),
    nest_shape=(1, ),
):

    # custom dtype for random lists
    mydtype = [
        ('randonlist', 'f', nest_shape)
    ]
    a = np.empty(shape, dtype=mydtype)
    # [DOC] moditfying array values
    # https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values
    # enable per operation flags 'readwrite' to modify element in ndarray
    # enable global flag 'refs_ok' to allow use callable function 'gen' in iteration
    with np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite'], flags=['refs_ok']) as it:
        for x in it:
            # pack list in a 1-d turple to prevent numpy boardcast it
            x[...] = (gen(nest_shape[0]), )

    return a


def test_get_matrix_from_numpy():
    gen = np.random.rand  # generator of random list
    shape = (6, 100)      # shape of matrix to hold random lists
    nest_shape = (11, )   # shape of random lists
    return get_matrix_from_numpy(gen, shape, nest_shape)
# access a random list by a[row][col][0]


# %timeit test_get_matrix_from_numpy()


# %%
def test_get_matrix_from_numpy():
    gen = np.random.rand
    shape = (6, 100)
    nest_shape = (11, )
    return get_matrix_from_numpy(gen, shape, nest_shape)


# %%
def old_calc_tstat(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = get_matrix_from_builtin()
        a = np.array(a)
    rows, cols = a.shape[:2]
    tstats = np.zeros(shape=(rows, cols))
    for i in range(0, rows):
        for j in range(1, cols):
            lg = linregress(a[i][0][0], a[i][j][0])
            tstats[i, j-1] = lg.slope/lg.stderr

    return tstats


# %%
def new_calc_tstat(a=None):
    # read input metrix of random lists
    if a is None:
        gen = np.random.rand
        shape = (6, 100)
        nest_shape = (11, )
        a = get_matrix_from_numpy(gen, shape, nest_shape)
    # construct ndarray for t-stat result
    tstats = np.empty(a.shape)
    # enable global flags 'multi_index' to retrive index of current element
    # [DOC] Tracking an Index or Multi-Index
    # https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index
    it = np.nditer(tstats, op_flags=['readwrite'], flags=['multi_index'])
    # obtain total columns count of tstats's shape
    col = tstats.shape[1]
    for x in it:
        i, j = it.multi_index
        # trick to avoid IndexError: substract len(list) after +1 to index
        j = j + 1 - col
        lg = linregress(
            a[i][0][0],
            a[i][j][0]
        )
        # note: nditer ignore ZeroDivisionError by default, and return np.inf to the element
        # you have to override it manually:
        if lg.stderr == 0:
            x[...] = 0
        else:
            x[...] = lg.slope / lg.stderr
    return tstats


# new_calc_tstat()


# %%
def test_equal():
    """Test if the new method has equal output to old one"""
    # use same input list to avoid affect of rand
    a = test_get_matrix_from_numpy()
    old = old_calc_tstat(a)
    new = new_calc_tstat(a)
    print(
        "Is the shape of old and new same ?\n%s. old: %s, new: %s\n" % (
            old.shape == new.shape, old.shape, new.shape),
    )
    res = (old == new)
    print(
        "Is the result object same?"
    )
    if res.all() == True:
        print("True.")
    else:
        print("False. Difference(new - old) as below:\n")
        print(new - old)

    return old, new


old, new = test_equal()


# %%
# the only diff is the last element
# in old method it is 0
# in new method it is inf
# if you perfer the old method, just add condition in new method to override
# [new[x][99] for x in range(6)]


# %%
# python version: 3.8.8

timer = time.clock if sys.platform[:3] == 'win' else time.time


def total(func, *args, _reps=1, **kwargs):
    start = timer()
    for i in range(_reps):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
    elapsed = timer() - start
    return elapsed


def test_perf():
    """Test of performance"""
    # first, get a larger input array
    gen = np.random.rand
    shape = (1000, 100)
    nest_shape = (30, )
    a = get_matrix_from_numpy(gen, shape, nest_shape)

    # repeat how many time for each test
    reps = 1

    # then, time both old and new calculation method
    old = total(old_calc_tstat, a, _reps=reps)
    new = total(new_calc_tstat, a, _reps=reps)

    msg = "Time elapsed to run %d times on %s is %f seconds."
    print(msg % (reps, 'new method', new))
    print(msg % (reps, 'old method', old))


test_perf()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. I am still getting through the whole thing but this is very helpful. Much appreciated!